# How to convert GMT time into Local time show the exact time

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I am making an app which can be access any where so let say i am uploading video at GMT time 5:30 AM so if the user in Pakistan see that video it should show him time in Local when did the video upload instead of 5:30 AM GMT. I am using following code to convert but it did not work for me .

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-17 05:30 AM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"]; 

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm: a"];
[dateFormatter2 setTimeZone:currentTimeZone];

NSDate *dateNew = [dateFormatter2 dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);
```

`NSLog` of both respectively is

```
date : 2013-12-16 19:30:00 +0000 2013-12-17 12:20:27.006 TimeTesting[1548:f803]
date : 2013-12-16 19:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: "It did not work for me" doesn't tell us anything about what happened. Note that "HH" is inappropriate if you've also got "a" - you want "hh". Also note that you haven't set the time zone for `dateFormatter1` - perhaps you need to set that to UTC?

Comment: @JonSkeet why to set UTC as dateFormatter is assume in GMT

Comment: Is it definitely? I wasn't sure, and I can't easily see it in the documentation. As you haven't told us what's going wrong, I'm really just groping around in the dark to work out what's happening. *Please* tell us what you're seeing rather than making us guess.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have shown you the NSLog of both dates as shown above in the question please check

Comment: I've just noticed that in both cases you're *parsing* with the `NSDateFormatter` - I'd expect you to parse with one, and format with the other. But given that you're getting the same output with or without the time zone being explicitly set to the local time zone, I suspect that it *does* default to the local zone. (Even if it didn't, being explicit about it would make the code clearer.) Again, you need to fix the `HH` as well.

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` by default has localTimeZone. If the provided dateString has info of the timeZone it would work flawlessly on pretty much everywhere no need to do anything else. But generally it is a thumb rule to assume that a given dateString is in UTC if no timezone is provided. But since the `NSDateFormatter` defaults to local time zone it leads to all sort of date conversion errors. So the work around would be to always feed dateFormatter a dateString with timeZone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 -(NSDate *)getLocalTimeFrom:(NSDate *)GMTTime
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSLog(@"%@",tz);
    NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: GMTTime];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)seconds);
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: GMTTime];
}
```

Comment: This method will return the local time for the time you are using as its argument.
Here, GMTTime stands for the absolute time(or UTCTime) you want it convert to local time.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution to the problem. What you are suggesting 'fixes' the problem of a 'GMT' date being incorrectly instantiated as if it were in the user's locale, but it does not address the root of the problem (i.e., A GMT date should be instantiated with a timezone offset of 0), see my answer below. Your solution requires the creation of 2 NSDates every time a GMT Date is created (the original, incorrect one, and your 'fixed' one)

Answer (score 0):

By default, NSDateFormatter will use the timezone associated with the current locale when creating a date from a string. So when you get the date from the string using your following method:

```
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"]; 
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];
```

you are inadvertently creating a date using the phone's locale timezone, so a value of 8AM GMT becomes 8AM in the user's timezone, not 8AM GMT.
All you need to do to correct this is set the locale for the date formatter you use to create the the date to be GMT 0, as the following code describes:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-17 05:30 AM";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
//explicitly set the timezone for the date formatter, so it will treat dates parsed in as GMT 0
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"GMT date : %@",[df stringFromDate:date]);

//create a new date formatter to use in displaying in the UI, which by default will use the user's locale and timezone
NSDateFormatter *userLocaleDF  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[userLocaleDF setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];

NSLog(@"date in user's locale/timezone: %@",[userLocaleDF stringFromDate:date]);
```